# Is it possible to temporarily disable an Oracle database link

Tags: oracle11g, dblink

Here is the situation.
We have an Oracle 11g database where one schema user has a private database link to a remote database. When the user initiates a certain process, it pulls a large amount of data across and slows down the other applications. We would like to limit when this user can access this remote database by disabling the database link during certain times of the day and then enable it when performance is not an issue.
I have not been able to find a way short of locking the user or dropping the database link to do this. Changing the open_links system parameter, I believe, requires a restart and that affects the other database links as well.

Does anyone have a clever way to implement this kind of restriction?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a thought: maybe you could have a scheduled process that grants/revokes select privileges to the dblink user on the main table at certain times?

Comment: Tony, you mean from the remote side? The remote DB is a third party, we have no control other than the userid they provide us. I'd like to be able to control it from our side.The userid that owns the DB-link is the user using it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Solution is to enable Resource Manger.  Limit the CPU or RAM as per your requirement. 
You can enable 2 profiles , one with more cpu/RAM/IO  and other with less resources and enable them as per your requirement.
Refer:
https://blogs.oracle.com/db/oracle-resource-manager-and-dbmsresourcemanager

Comment: This solution does not really help in limiting the use of a DB Link

Comment: This doesn't limit the use of DB link but this limit the resource availability for other process on the server so that other will not run out of system resources.